# Python Console Issue no ">>>"

Tags: console

I realize this is a ridiculous question but I can't figure out how to fix this. My python console doesn't work. Instead of ">>>" it shows In[# adds 1 each type I hit enter]. And if I put multiple lines of code and hit enter, they don't run instead I get ..: underneath

Code will only run if its in code window and I hit play which is time consuming and not helping.

Can anyone help me as to what to do?

Comment: It sounds like you're using a custom python repl like ipython, it's no big deal and has tons of useful features. The ... You mentioned means you need to press enter again, or the repl is still expecting a closing character ( typically a `)`, `}`, etc ). To use a normal python repl, try to get out of the environment you're in or just type in `python` or `python3` in your shell

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate the help

Comment: So I'm still having the issue that anytime I run a line in the console, absolutely nothing happens, e.g. only get ...:

Comment: So I'm still having the issue that anytime I run a line in the console, absolutely nothing happens, e.g. only get ...: for example I try and run the code: distance.euclidean([1,1,0], [1,1,1]) it will only cause the next line to be ...: and now, I am no longer able to write a "(" in the console line. Any suggestions? I've already redownloaded the anaconda/python